# NuGet downloads all packages, doesn't update references

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have my project set to `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` as well as `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio`. In my solution folder, there is a packages folder and it contains everything that I need for my project. However the references to them in the project are still broken.

I have tried removing the references and adding them with NuGet, but NuGet says the item is already in the project (it is in the packages folder) even though the reference is there and the project can't build. The only way that I can seem to get around it is to manually go into each of the packages in the packages folder and select every .dll.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open package manager console and type:

`Update-Package -Reinstall`

This should refresh all your references based on each project's *packages.config* file.